# How to remove a specific script from bulk wordpress posts and images description?

Tags: posts, admin, tags

My site got hacked and I found  on the end of each post and image description. Is there any way to remove it?

Thank you
Gusti

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

For sure not only your Posts include Code. There will be also hacked php files. Cleaning the posts wont help until the secuity hole is fixed.
After closing the secuity hole you could use [Better Search an Replace](https://en.wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) for Replacing the Code.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. Is that mean my theme has security hole or the wordpress core files?

Comment: If WordPress is up to date, then it should be secure.  No known vulnerabilities with the current release. Chances are it's your theme, one of the plugins you use, or if you're on a shared hosting platform, it may not even be your site but rather another site on the shared server. (Haven't seen it often, but have seen it happen.)